# Has anyone 'integrated' databases using an ontology tool such as Protege?

Tags: database, integration, protege

I don't know that 'integrated' is the correct word, but has anyone had to build a knowledge base by integrating multiple disparate databases together? For example, if I were to build an ontology linking a car value ($) database with my personal finance database, I'd want to be able to build a query to find out "Can I buy a Delorian?" I'm wondering what tools/methods people have used to build this sort of thing.